# SQL to Linq --> select max and min

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I m trying to get the country for a particular IP address, the IP are stored by range ( long integer) in the DB

I have the following SQL query :

```
select * from dbo.ip
where IP_From = ( select max(IP_From) 
            from dbo.ip
            where IP_From <= @ipAddress 
            ) 
and IP_To = ( 
        select min(IP_To) 
            from dbo.ip
            where IP_To >= @ipAddress 
                )
```

Data in the database

```
IP_From     IP_To       Registry
16777728    16778239    apnic   1302739200  CN  CHN China
16778240    16779263    apnic   1302566400  AU  AUS Australia
16779264    16781311    apnic   1302566400  CN  CHN China
16781312    16785407    apnic   1302566400  JP  JPN Japan
16785408    16793599    apnic   1302566400  CN  CHN China
16793600    16809983    apnic   1302566400  JP  JPN Japan
16809984    16842751    apnic   1302220800  TH  THA Thailand
```

I m trying :

```
    //string strHttpClientIP = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    string strHttpClientIP = "58.8.247.169";
    var splitIP = strHttpClientIP.Split('.');
    var a = splitIP[0];
    var b = splitIP[1];
    var c = splitIP[2];
    Int64 intIPFrom = FunctionsGlobal.IP2Int(Convert.ToString(a + "." + b + "." + c + ".0"));
    Int64 intIPTo = FunctionsGlobal.IP2Int(Convert.ToString(a + "." + b + "." + c + ".255"));

    var IPList = db.IpToCountries;

     var MaxIpFrom = IPList.Max(i => i.IP_From);
    var MinIpTo = IPList.Min(i => i.IP_To);
    var QueryCurrency = IPList.Where(i=>i.IP_From == MaxIpFrom && i.IP_To == MinIpTo);
```

Which i d like to convert to a Linq c# query, any clues ?

Comment: what type `IP_From` and `IP_To`? Can you provide what you try in c#?

Comment: What @Grundy says, plus can you add a sample of the data you're querying against ?

Comment: @Yann ok :-) now show how you work with db from c# code

Comment: @Yann your code not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
from ip in IPList
let maxIp = IPList.Where(a=>a.IP_From <= ipAddress).Max(a=>a.IP_From) 
let minIp = IPList.Where(a=>a.IP_To >= ipAddress).Min(a=>a.IP_To)
where ip.IP_From == maxIp && ip.IP_To == minIp
```